# Primitive TODO and FIXME script

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a simple script to search a document for TODO: and FIXME: and return the match plus the line numbers. I've got a (very bad) version of it working, and I'm now wondering how to do it correctly.

I need to turn this:

```
todo: alpha
bravo
fixme: charlie
fixme: delta
echo
frank
todo: golf
```

Into this:

```
1 - todo: alpha
7 - todo: golf
3 - fixme: charlie
4 - fixme: delta
```

Notice that the numbered result is sorted by tag.

Comment: Try posting your current code. Then, the answers can be built upon that. Also, try to clarify what a solution that is not "very bad" means to you: cleanness, performance, maintainability, robustness, elegance?

Comment: Please show the version you have...

Comment: There are any number of ways to do it. Including using things like grep and sort-I assume this is a learning exercise though.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I over-generalized my question.I wanted to see how other people would do it, so I could learn from their methods - without consideration for how I approached the problem. If this isn't a place for that kind of exploration I'll take it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
doc = <<DOC
todo: alpha
bravo
fixme: charlie
fixme: delta
echo
frank
todo: golf
DOC

doc.split("\n").map.with_index {|s,i| [i,s]}.select {|(i,s)| s.include?("todo:")|| \
  s.include?("fixme:")}.sort_by(&:last).map {|(i, s)| "#{i+1} - " + s}

   => ["3 - fixme: charlie",
       "4 - fixme: delta",
       "1 - todo: alpha",
       "7 - todo: golf"]
```

By steps:

```
s1 = doc.split("\n").map.with_index {|s,i| [i,s]}
 => [[0, "todo: alpha"], [1, "bravo"], [2, "fixme: charlie"],
     [3, "fixme: delta"], [4, "echo"], [5, "frank"], [6, "todo: golf"]] 
s2 = s1.select {|(i,s)| s.include?("todo:") || s.include?("fixme:")}
 => [[0, "todo: alpha"], [2, "fixme: charlie"],
     [3, "fixme: delta"], [6, "todo: golf"]] 
s3 = s2.sort_by(&:last) # Equivalent to s2.sort_by {|a| a.last}
 => [[2, "fixme: charlie"], [3, "fixme: delta"],
     [0, "todo: alpha"], [6, "todo: golf"]] 
s3.map {|(i, s)| "#{i+1} - " + s}
 => ["3 - fixme: charlie", "4 - fixme: delta",
     "1 - todo: alpha", "7 - todo: golf"]
```

Comment: your code would also match `foo: bar`.

Comment: Thanks, sevenseacat, missed that. It's fixed now.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That clears things up.